# Почему после выполнения `df[cols].fillna('NA', inplace=True)` в DataFrame ничего не поменялось?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

На входе у меня есть `pandas.DataFrame`. Я хочу заполнить все пропуски константой. Делаю так:

```
data_categorical[categorical_cols].fillna('NA', inplace=True)
```

После чего проверяю, все ли сделано верно:

```
data_categorical[categorical_cols].isna().sum()
```

Вывод:

```
Var200    20366
Var214    20366
Var217      560
Var199        4
Var202        1
Var198        0
Var222        0
Var220        0
Var216        0
Var192      291
dtype: int64
```

Как видно из вывода, данные не изменились. Подскажите, почему данные не изменились? Как заполнить пропуски в данных используя `pandas.DataFrame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы заполнить пропуски в части DataFrame:

```
data_categorical.loc[:, categorical_cols] = data_categorical.loc[:, categorical_cols].fillna('NA')
```

или

```
data_categorical.loc[:, categorical_cols].fillna('NA', inplace=True)
```

PS если `data_categorical[categorical_cols]` идентичен по содержанию `data_categorical`, что следует из названий DF и списка столбцов, то можно упростить команду:

```
data_categorical = data_categorical.fillna('NA')
```

---

> Почему следующая конструкция не работает?

```
df[col_list].fillna('NA', inplace=True)
```

Потому что `df[col_list]` создает *копию* части DataFrame и заполняется копия, а исходный DF остается незатронутым.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296545/5741205) один из основных участников Pandas Core Team - Jeff объясняет в каких случаях создается копия DataFrame.